# Benefits of using Inherit Forms Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

I tryed to create new components from one base Windows Form, also I found difficulties when I worked with toolstrip components, for example :

how to bind a datagrid.datasource on a child form using events from a button (clicks) on the parent toolstrip?

I have to use some snippets on each child form for doing this, btw why?

```
// btnSearch
// 
this.btnSearch.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnExec_Click);

private void btnExec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//do stuff
}
```

Thanks

EDIT: I also know about modifiers issue :

[image]

I mean, I have to replace the toolstripbutton with a common button, also have to add more code on designer class (base form) :

```
grpCommonControls.Height = 20;
dtTScomponent = new ToolStripControlHost(grpCommonControls);
dtTScomponent.Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Right;
toolStrip1.Items.Add(dtTScomponent);


tssbExporta.Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Left;
toolStrip1.Items.Add(tssbExporta);
```

I was needed to add a simple toolstrip with some toolstrip controls on my base form, but the designer dont allow me to work correctly with those (I cannot route the events from toolstripbutton to my child forms as an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a form that inherits another form that contains different controls, there are not event handlers automatically hooked up for you. Instead you need to do that as in your code sample. Another approach is to attach that event handler in your base form, and then have the base form expose events that you can listen to. Example:

In the base form:

```
public event EventHandler ExecInvoked;
private void btnExec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     OnExecInvoked(e);
}

protected virtual void OnExecInvoked(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler evt = ExecInvoked;
    if (evt != null)
    {
        evt(this, e);
    }
}
```

Then, in your inherited form, you can either set up an event handler for the `ExecInvoked` event (you can probably do this using the events list in the property grid), or you can override the `OnExecInvoked` method:

```
protected override void OnExecInvoked(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnExecInvoked(e);

    // do what the form should do when Exec is invoked
}
```

This way you have encapsulated the internals of the base form, so that the child form does not know what kind of control that raises the event (it could even be several different controls leading to the same event being raised), but the base form still provides a clear point where the child form can react on it.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to change properties and subscribe to events of controls inherited from your parent Form (or UserControl), the parent form should set those controls' `Modifiers` property to `protected` (or, in general, to any value such that fields generated for controls in parent form are visible to the child form). The default value for `Modifiers` is `private`.

Comment: Correct in principal but I have noticed the designer ignoring this on occasion. Even after a rebuild.